# URLSession willPerformHTTPRedirection not called on redirect

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I need to obtain the redirect URL from a request, and I understand the way to do this is within `willPerformHTTPRedirection`.

When I try my code with a URL like `http://gmail.com`, the redirect request IS noticed and processed through `willPerformHTTPRedirection` but other URLs, the redirect is processed but `willPerformHTTPRedirection` IS NOT called.

For example, the following URL `https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=045496590420&type=prices` does not call `willPerformHTTPRedirection`. If I turn off automatic redirects in Postman I can see the redirect URL in the Location header.  How can I obtain this same info with URLSession?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var session : URLSession?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=045496590420&type=prices")!
        var requestHeader = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        requestHeader.httpMethod = "GET"

        session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)


        session?.dataTask(with: requestHeader, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if let l = response.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Location") {
                print("location", l)
            }
            
            print(response)

            
        }
        print("data is here")
        print(response?.url)
    }).resume()

}

}



extension ViewController: URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
    print("stop redirect")
   
    completionHandler(nil)
    
}
}
```

curl result on the url:

```
curl -i --head "https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=045496590420&type=prices"
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://www.pricecharting.com/game/nintendo-switch/zelda-breath-of-the-wild?q=045496590420
X-Appengine-Log-Flush-Count: 0
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: c2b9bab298c4d01e21a33759cdc99175
Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2021 23:06:21 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Are you sure it is actually getting a redirect when requested by iOS, and that the server's redirection behavior isn't specific to certain user agent strings or perhaps http versus https?  I don't get a redirect from the server when I hit that URL with curl on the command line.

Comment: If i turn off automatic redirects in postman and hit that address, i get status 307 temporary redirect, and i get a location header with a url.  in a browser this also redirects.  can i replicate the results im getting from postman?

Comment: @dgatwood i updated the original post with my curl results, im getting a 307

Comment: Interesting.  Now I'm getting the same thing.  A few hours ago, I got a URL.  I wonder if curl's default redirect handling behavior is different in Big Sur than in Mojave.  :-/

Comment: Ultimately, it was your suggestion that led me to the answer.  I am converting barcode to UPC, and i was mistakenly converting it to an integer.  Integers dont start with 0 and UPC does.  Keeping UPC as a string kept the 0. this url ```https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=045496590420&type=prices``` works as it should because its status 307.  this url ```https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=45496590420&type=prices``` does not because its status 200.  As long as im not an idiot and feed it the correct URL it works as it should.   Should i mark yours as the answer?

Comment: LOL.  Write up an answer and mark it as answered.  I didn't actually write one.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code is correct and working as desired.  The code came prior to the call.

I am converting barcode to UPC, and i was mistakenly converting it to an integer. Integers dont start with 0 and UPC does. Keeping UPC as a string kept the 0.

Given this, the following URL works as it should because its status 307:

```
https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=045496590420&type=prices
```

This URL does not because its status 200:

```
https://www.pricecharting.com/search-products?q=45496590420&type=prices
```